# Error validating datasource `db`: the URL must start with the protocol `mongo`

Tags: next.js, prisma, vercel

```
ERROR   PrismaClientInitializationError: Invalid
 `prisma.chat.findMany()` invocation:error: Error
 validating datasource `db`: the URL must start with the 
protocol `mongo`.  
-->  schema.prisma:10  
 |  9 |   provider = "mongodb"
   10 |  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")   
      | Validation Error Count: 1
```

Different type of methods I've tried so far:

- Renaming mongodb to mongo in database URL
- Removing the quotes in vercel enviroment variables
- adding the enviroment variable to vercel.json
- All my environment variables are already in my vercel environments for my project

Works perfectly fine in Dev -> Build -> Start in vscode.

How do you deploy on vercel with prisma mongodb URL error?
Ive seen the same error for others but with different db.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your [environment variables](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables) in Vercel. Vercel won't have access to your local .env file.

Comment: They were defined in vercel  in that example. But they were deployed for both preview and production maybe I’ll try making it only for production and whitelisting all on mongodb

Comment: If it helps, here is an example of deploying prisma app to Vercel: https://github.com/prisma/deployment-example-vercel